# Hide / Invisible Matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a question, not sure if its difficult or not, but i tried to google the answer. nothing worthy.

I have figure as global, which can be accessed in all threads.

but it appears in the beginning of the program,

I want to hide or making it invisible in the starting of the script then at one point in the code make it available or visible.

Is there is any Matplotlib like visible False or something

i use this:

```
plt.ion()

fig = plt.figure(visible=False)

ax =fig.add_subplot(111)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

There is a [nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32576093/4124317) how to toggle visibility of a complete matplotlib figure in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28463479/how-to-toggle-visibility-of-matplotlib-figures?noredirect=1&lq=1). 
The idea is to use the `.set_visible` method of the figure.

Here a complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter([1,2,3], [2,3,1], s=40)

def toggle_plot(event):
  # This function is called by a keypress to hide/show the figure
  plt.gcf().set_visible(not plt.gcf().get_visible())
  plt.draw()

cid = plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", toggle_plot)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, avoid using `plt.ion()` in scripts. It is meant to be used only in interactive sessions, where you want to see the result of matplotlib commands immediately.

In a script, the drawing is usually delayed until `plt.show` is called:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(range(5))

plt.show()  # now the figure is shown
```

Comment: Thank you I solved it in away that i initialize it only for the first time by a flag,
but if i don't use the ion, i dont see any changes on the image

Answer (score 1):

I have to do the same thing that you're asking for, but I put the figure on a canvas first using this process (NOTE: this uses matplotlib, pyplot, and wxPython):

```
#Define import and simplify how things are called
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Make a panel
panel = wx.Panel(self)

#Make a figure
self.figure = plt.figure("Name")
#The "Name" is not necessary, but can be useful if you have lots of plots

#Make a canvas
self.canvas = FigureCanvas(panel, -1, self.figure)

#Then use
self.canvas.Show(True)
#or
self.canvas.Show(False)

#You can also check the state of the canvas using (probably with an if statement)
self.canvas.IsShown()
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to hide the entire plot window, and you are using the tk backend - you can use the Toplevel() widget from the tkinter library.

Here is a full example:

```
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg

fig,(ax) = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi)
y = np.transpose([np.sin(x)])
ax.plot(y)

graph = Toplevel()
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=graph)
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
canvas.show()

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, graph)
toolbar.update()
```

Calling:

```
graph.withdraw()
```

will hide the plot window, and:

```
graph.deiconify()
```

will display it again.

Comment: Nobody asked about Tkinter here.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Of course, but this does get the job done. Why should it not be done this way?

Comment: This is a very backend specific solution, and since the tk backend is not the standard backend, the answer at least needs to mention this fact. Additionally, it's pretty overkill, since you can simply use `fig.set_visible(False)` (as seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32576093/4124317)).

Comment: Okay, I was looking for a solution to try and hide the entire plot window. `fig.set_visible(False)` seems to only blank out the plot itself.