# How to toggle visibility of matplotlib figures?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way that I can make a matplotlib figure disappear and reappear in response to some event? (i.e. a keypress)

I've tried using `fig.set_visible(False)` but that doesn't seem to do anything for me.

Simple example of code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig=matplotlib.pyplot.figure(figsize=(10, 10))

# Some other code will go here

def toggle_plot():
  # This function is called by a keypress to hide/show the figure
  fig.set_visible(not fig.get_visible()) # This doesn't work for me

plt.show()
```

The reason I'm trying to do this is because I have a bunch of plots/animations running on the figure that show the output of a running simulation, but displaying them all the time slows down my computer a lot. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide / Invisible Matplotlib figure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629438/hide-invisible-matplotlib-figure)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to call `plt.draw()` to actually instantiate any changes. This should work:

```
def toggle_plot():
  # This function is called by a keypress to hide/show the figure
  fig.set_visible(not fig.get_visible())
  plt.draw()
```

Comment: The figure is being hidden, but it still occupies the space in the jupyter lab output cell.

Comment: I tested and confirm it only hides the contents of the figure window and not the window itself.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [small guide to image toggling](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/toggle_images.html) in the matplotlib gallery. I was able to use `set_visible` and `get_visible()` as shown in the example. The calls in the matplotlib gallery example are on `AxesImage` instances, rather than `Figure` instances, as in your example code. That is my guess as to why it did not work for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can you use the Toplevel() widget from the tkinter library together with the matplotlib backend.

Here is a full example:

```
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

fig,(ax) = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi)
y = np.transpose([np.sin(x)])
ax.plot(y)

graph = Toplevel()
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,master=graph)
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid()
canvas.show()

import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Calling:

```
graph.withdraw()
```

will hide the plot, and:

```
graph.deiconify()
```

will display it again.